# Reshape PyTorch tensor so that matrices are horizontal

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I'm trying to combine `n` matrices in a 3-dimensional PyTorch tensor of shape `(n, i, j)` into a single 2-dimensional matrix of shape `(i, j*n)`. Here's a simple example where `n=2, i=2, j=2`:

```
m = torch.tensor([[[2, 3],
                   [5, 7]],
                  [[11, 13],
                   [17, 19]]])
m.reshape(2, 4)
```

I was hoping this would produce:

```
tensor([[ 2,  3, 11, 13],
        [ 5,  7, 17, 19]])
```

But instead it produced:

```
tensor([[ 2,  3,  5,  7],
        [11, 13, 17, 19]])
```

How do I do this? I tried `torch.cat` and `torch.stack`, but they require tuples of tensors. I could try and create tuples, but that seems inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine `n` + `j` with `reshape` you need them consequent in shape. One can fix it with `swapaxes`:

```
m = torch.tensor([[[2, 3],
               [5, 7]],
              [[11, 13],
               [17, 19]]])
m=m.swapaxes( 0,1 ) 
m.reshape(2, 4)
```

---

```
tensor([[ 2,  3, 11, 13],
        [ 5,  7, 17, 19]])
```